# Splitting space turns to breakline in second string

Tags: perl

This is the sample text file I want to split.

```
00:11:22:33:44:55(space)s8g6Dg9C11Dz97Fx(breakline)
XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX(space)XXXXXXXXxxxXXxXx
```

After spliting it, the last line turns to

```
s8g6Dg9C11Dz97Fx(breakline)
```

Instead of

```
s8g6Dg9C11Dz97Fx(nothing).
```

But

```
00:11:22:33:44:55 and XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

is ok.

This is the code:

```
($mcaddr,$auth) = split / /;
```

I fix this problem by adding space in end of the line.

Comment: Please provide a runnable demonstration of your problem. At the very least, please provide the output of `printf("%v02X", $str)`

Comment: `chomp` your line before splitting it.`

Comment: This is the code open( tarrget, "<$ARGV[0]" ) or die "$!";
while (<tarrget>) {
    chomp($_);
    $target = $_;
    ( $mcaddr, $auth ) = split / /;
    ( $mcadd,  $none ) = split / /;
    $mcadd =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]*//g;

Comment: Because he is getting an extra space at the end, which is probably his line ending.

Comment: I think the problem is split / /;

Comment: If that's suppose to your be your demonstration, it should be in the question. That said, it doesn't demonstrate your problem; it dies for lack of an input file. Please provide a runnable demonstration of your problem. At the very least, please provide the output of `printf("%v02X", $str)`

Comment: This is the code and logs http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=URAn8vdz

Comment: Your code and sample data should be in your question. Don't use offsite links - they go invalid. Indeed, already has!.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is:

```
open(tarrget, "<$ARGV[0]" ) or die "$!";
while (<tarrget>) {
  chomp($_);
  $target = $_;  ## Not used...
  ( $mcaddr, $auth ) = split / /;
  ( $mcadd, $none ) = split / /;
  $mcadd =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]*//g;
}
```

I saw that you use *split* in **$_** twice and then try to erase non-alphanumeric chars in the $mcadd variable.

Try this:

1. Put your content in a file named "mac.list";
2. Run this perl-oneliner (the *pipes* "|" are just to "clarify" your output):

   perl -nE 'chomp; ($m, $a) = split /\s+/; $m =~ s/[^A-F0-9]//ig; say "|$m|"; say "|$a|";' mac.list

#

My *output* based on your 2 examples:

```
|001122334455|
|s8g6Dg9C11Dz97Fx|
||
|XXXXXXXXxxxXXxXx|
```

**Note:** The `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` are not hexadecimal valid (not A-F nor 0-9) and are erased in `"$m =~ s/[^A-F0-9]//ig;"`

For those that are not used to Perl's `s///` and RegExp...:
`[^A-F]` => not A to F;
`[^0-9]` => not 0 to 9;
The `i` modifier stands for "ignore case";
The `g` modifier stands for "global";

Hope this snippet / one-liner be useful to you.

Comment: I fix this problem by adding space in the end of the line.

Comment: Try the one-liner in a smaller case and then adapt to your code, with the **pipes** in the output, you can figure out if there is an extra character in your input. Try to run `$ file mclist.txt` to see if it uses Windows line-endings `\r\n` or `vim mclist.txt` to see if there is something wrong with the input file...

Comment: livemac.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: By adding space at the end, you'll get an extra variable in split, that catches the extra chars (probably `\r` or another non-printable char.)... add an extra var. in your split and print it between _pipes_ to see if the variable is defined or not, you can print the char. code with [chr function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html) or [ord function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html)

Comment: Hum... try to run `dos2unix -k livemac.txt` to convert the line-endings to Unix terminators (just `\n` instead of `\r\n`). This way I think you can remove the extra space in the end of lines... `vim` tells you that the file has EOL `\r\n` in that `[dos]` in the end of the terminal / screen, in your print-screen...

Comment: root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/WiMAX# dos2unix -k livemac.txt
dos2unix: converting file livemac.txt to Unix format ...
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/WiMAX#

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing the code to:

```
open( tarrget, "<$ARGV[0]" ) or die "$!";
while (<tarrget>) {
    chomp($_);
    ( $mcaddr, $none ) = split / /;
    ( $mcadd,  $none ) = split / /;
    ( $none,  $auth ) = split / /;
    $mcadd =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]*//g;
```

Comment: `chomp` acts on `$_` anyway; `split` defaults to `$_` and "on whitespace". 3 arg open with lexical filehandles is preferable.